# Error: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to solve a problem with mysql configuration, but all the time have the same problem:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/test/config/DataBaseConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

So here we have my config files and I really hope for your help, because i have no idea what's the problem!

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {private final static String DISPATCHER = "dispatcher";                                      

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER, new DispatcherServlet(context));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

My DataBaseConfig class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("db.url"));
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));

        dataSource.setInitialSize(Integer.valueOf(environment.getProperty("db.initialize")));
        dataSource.setMinIdle(Integer.valueOf(environment.getProperty("db.minIdle")));
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(Integer.valueOf(environment.getProperty("db.maxIdle")));
        dataSource.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(Long.valueOf(environment.getProperty("db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis")));
        dataSource.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(Long.valueOf(environment.getProperty("db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis")));
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(Boolean.valueOf(environment.getProperty("db.testOnBorrow")));
        dataSource.setValidationQuery(environment.getProperty("db.validationQuery"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(environment.getProperty("db.entity.package"));
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return entityManager;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hibernate.properties")) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(inputStream);
            return properties;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find 'hibernate.properties' in classpath!", e);
        }


    }
}
```

For Webconfig i use the class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.test")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Database properties file:

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?serverTimezone=Europe/Minsk&useSSL=false
db.username=root
db.password=root
db.entity.package = com.test.domain

#dbcp configure
db.initialize = 30
db.minIdle = 30
db.maxIdle = 30
db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 30000
db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
db.testOnBorrow = true
db.validationQuery = select version()`
```

And another file for hibernate config:

```
#Hibernate Configuration:
db.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
db.hibernate.show_sql=true
db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
```

All dependencies seem to be correct and username and password too. What can be the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>5.1.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <javax.annotation>1.3.2</javax.annotation>
        <javax.servlet>4.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <spring-data>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data>
        <hb.manager>5.0.2.Final</hb.manager>
        <mysql.version>5.1.47</mysql.version>
        <dbcp2.version>2.6.0</dbcp2.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.annotation}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--WEB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Database-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hb.manager}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${dbcp2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you share full stack trace, please?

Comment: Try to update mysql-connector-java. Change "db.driver" too.

Comment: I've already changed dependencies in pom file and i dont know why, but it works! thanks a lot :)